# Magento 2 Custom PHP code in Admin email template

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I have an email template that I'm updating using the Magento admin interface.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is get the Order ID, hash it, and send it as part of the email.

I read that PHP short tags can be used in email templates, but all of them render blank when the email is actually sent.  Here are a few variations I've tried:

```
   <div>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
        <p><?php echo 'Hello World';?>
        <p><?php 'Hello World';?>
        <p><?= 'Hello World';?>
    </div>
```

'Hello World' is not echoed out in any of these scenarios.

My question is, is it possible to inject PHP code directly into the templates via the admin portal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you trying get the order id  right??

Comment: @MohitPatel I'm trying to get the order id, and then run some kind of hash command on it.  Example <?php echo hash('ripemd160', $orderId);?>

Comment: but php is not support in email template

Comment: i have use the your code please check screen short :- 1> https://prnt.sc/r83tj0
2> https://prnt.sc/r83tp0

see two screen sort and conform the not support the php

Comment: @MohitPatel I was following this documentation, which says at the bottom that PHP is supported
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html

Comment: i am check and this php use the direct the block folder php file functions use
you use the this type <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>

direct block function return values get ??

Comment: @amb44371 - the templates the documentation is referring to is for web pages, not for email templates. afaik, raw php isn't supported in email templates, but values are generated in php, and then passed to the email templates, which render them with a different syntax. Take a look at vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html - you can see that the order id is rendered as '<h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>'